# JBoss 5.1 won't start - using eclipse on mac osx

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I'm trying to start Jboss application server 5.1 on eclipse with jdk 6 (java version "1.6.0_37")  running on a mac.

The problem is the server status never turns to "started" and when timeout time has passed I receive an error on eclipse - "server failed to start"

I tried changing ports on the  "jboss-service.xml" file  but it didn't help.

Any idea or insight as to why this is happening ,what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Attached is an excerpt of the console output.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.setCatalinaHome(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatService.startService(TomcatService.java:183)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:376)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.pojoStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:216)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1568)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1533)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:943)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1568)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1533)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:943)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
22:10:48,271 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vf
```

.....

```
 22:10:50,423 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/ROOT" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/admin-console" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/invoker" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jbossws" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jmx-console" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/web-console" is missing the following dependencies:
Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.setCatalinaHome(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   Deployment "jboss.web:service=WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s): **  NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **

 22:10:50,424 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 27s:111ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - if you're starting a server which was setup in eclipse, there is a timeout property which can be changed - i have to extend the timeout on one of our test machines because it takes about 5 minutes to start up and the default is about 2 minutes i think.

Do you have any other instances of JBoss or Tomcat running on the machine?

Looking at the deployment erros, a quick google reveals: https://community.jboss.org/message/749362
, https://community.jboss.org/thread/148647
& https://community.jboss.org/thread/163772

Do these help?

Comment: I already set timeout to 450 seconds.
anyway, I found out i had  Tomcat jar files in my system/library/java directory.
Deleting them solved the problem.
thanks anyway...